# Angular 2 - Reactive Forms validation for one field only in loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building a form within an array:

```
buildGuestDetails(arr) {
        var resultArr = [];
        arr.forEach(x => {
            resultArr.push(this.fBuilder.group({
                id: x.id,
                forename: x.forename,
                surname: [x.surname, Validators.required],
                email: x.email,
                telephone: x.telephone,
                specialInstructions: x.specialInstructions,
                dietaryRequirements: this.buildDietaryRequirements(x.dietaryRequirements)
            }))
        });
        return this.fBuilder.array(resultArr);
    }
```

But I am to only put the validation on the very first "surname", all the other surnames churned out from the array are not to have the validation.
Is it a simple case of seeing if index equals 0 or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the `index==0`

```
buildGuestDetails(arr) {
        var resultArr = [];
        arr.forEach((x,index) => {
            resultArr.push(this.fBuilder.group({
                id: x.id,
                forename: x.forename,
                surname: [x.surname, index == 0 ? Validators.required : undefined],
                email: x.email,
                telephone: x.telephone,
                specialInstructions: x.specialInstructions,
                dietaryRequirements: this.buildDietaryRequirements(x.dietaryRequirements)
            }))
        });
        return this.fBuilder.array(resultArr);
    }
```

Comment: This is awesome thanks :) I didn't know you could do those type of if operators on the typescript side as well as the template side. Many thanks for this. I will mark as the accepted answer once it allows me to :)

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward No Problem. Yes its valid Javascript, [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Been available since ES5. Thanks have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks you too :)